# json_encode change number into string

Tags: arrays, json, cakephp-2.3

I have an array which has some strings values and some numeric values. I used

```
json_encode
```

to convert array into json array but it convert numbers values into string which I do not want.

```
 [["India","2"],["Panama","1"]]
```

I tried

```
JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK
```

as second parameter in json_encode then it works fine on localhost but showing error online.

```
Use of undefined constant JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK - assumed '
```

I am using cakephp 2.3

Comment: what exactly do you want the output to be? `[["India",2],["Panama",1]]` would be invalid json

Comment: @andrew Why should that be invalid?

Comment: What error are you getting when you use the json decoded array of '[["India","2"],["Panama","1"]]' in cakephp 2.3?

Comment: @Ryan Vincent i am using Highchart, where i was getting error. I requires this format of array [["India",2],["Panama",1]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing online you have an older version of PHP:

> JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK (integer)
>
> Encodes numeric strings as numbers. *Available since PHP 5.3.3.*

When you JSON encode, it will not have quotes if PHP *knows* it is not a string.
If you need to do it manually, you could do something like this:

```
<?php

  function json_numeric($array)
  {
     if (is_array($array) || is_object($array)) {
        foreach($array as &$prop) {
            if (is_numeric($prop)) {
                $prop = intval($prop);
            }
            if (is_object($prop) || is_array($prop)) {
                $prop = json_numeric($prop);
            }
        }
     }
     return $array;
  }

  $x = array("a" => 1, "b" => "2", "c"=>array("d"=>1, "e"=>"2"));
  echo json_encode(json_numeric($x));
  //{"a":1,"b":2,"c":{"d":1,"e":2}}
  $y = new stdClass();
  $y->a = 1;
  $y->b = "2";
  echo json_encode(json_numeric($y));
  //{"a":1,"b":2}
?>
```

Comment: thank you. This error was due to php version. I updated my php version and it is now working fine.